# Unable to change the numeral font format at start of each chapter using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am facing a strange problem and hope it is a simple trick that I am missing. 
I am trying to use several custom fancypagestyle using fancyhdr to separate frontmatter,appendix and backmatter and main matter etc.

Now by default, the first page number is at the fancyfoot[c] for every chapter  and other front and backmatter. Initially I have not changed the fancyfoot[].

But when for a particular chapter style say appendix style I try to format \thepage style using fancyfoot[CO,CE] and fancyhead[LE,RO] using {\bfseries \sffamily \thepage}, it happens such that excluding first page of each chapter remaining pages font change works fine as per my custom font. How to rectify this.

In short, I  want to make the page numbering at the starting of each chapter as \bfseries \sffamily \thepage.

A MWE may be as follows

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}
  {
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\large \bfseries \sffamily \thepage}
%The first page of each chapter not changing but other pages ok
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \pagestyle{mystyle}

    \begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \chapter{Preface}
     \Blindtext
      \Blindtext          
      \chapter{About this book}
       \Blindtext
        \Blindtext        

    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{My Style Chapter}
    \blindtext
     \Blindtext        
    \section{My style section}
    \Blindtext
     \Blindtext

    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendix My Style}
    \blindtext

    \section{My Appendix section}
    \Blindtext
     \Blindtext        

    \backmatter       

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @albert, I have now added an MWE where it shows that first page of every new chapter is default style but second page onwards it formats as customized

Comment: Chapter pages uses page style `plain` by default. So you have to redefine this page style too.

Comment: @esdd, thanks for the idea, I am trying to get it,  would you please provide a brief idea how to set it as required custom font

Comment: @esdd, thanks, I have defined `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` for chapter page and it worked. Now format is ok.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments